# Serialize DTO based on authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

My Web API controllers should return different models based on whether or not the model the user is trying to get belongs to him.

So for example:

```
class Customer {
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public decimal Revenue { get; set; }
}
```

The corresponding action would be `Api/Customers/1`.

Now, if that model belongs to the user who's currently calling the action I would like to return all fields. If however somebody else calls the same action he should only see the `Id` and `Name` fields.

I'm aware you could return an interface and chose the implementation based on authentication level but I was wondering if there was something simpler like `[JsonIgnore]` but based on access level to accomplish the same? It would also help me reduce code duplication.

What's the most elegant way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use Conditional serialization of JSON.NET (if you are using JSON.NET). This [link](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/?topic=html/ConditionalProperties.htm) can help you more

```
To conditionally serialize a property add a boolean method with the same name as 
the property and then prefixed the method name with ShouldSerialize. 
The result of the method determines whether the property is serialized. 
If the method returns true then the property will be serialized, if it returns false
and the property will be skipped.
```

Other thing I can think of is override Object.ToString() method in your class which will return JSON as per your need. You still have to specify the condition, and on condition return JSON string of your choice.

Comment: Great! I didn't know about conditional serialization, that's exactly what I needed. Thank you.